# How can I disable Cross region replication in oracle cloud using ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I came across a situation where when deleting an image with CRR enabled, you must first disable CRR before you can successfully delete the image. I cannot come with an ansible role or task to do the same.

So far I've come up with this:

```
- name: Get information of all boot volume attachments in a compartment and availability domain
  oci_boot_volume_attachment_facts:
    compartment_id: "{{ COMPARTMENT_ID }}"
    availability_domain: "{{ Availability_Domain}}"
    instance_id: "{{ matching_id_instance }}"
  register: boot_volume_data


- name: Update boot_volume
  oci_blockstorage_boot_volume:
    # required
    boot_volume_id: "{{ item.boot_volume_id }}"
    boot_volume_replicas: []
    - # required
      availability_domain: "{{ Availability_Domain}}"
  with_items: "{{ boot_volume_data.boot_volume_attachments }}"
  when:
        - item.instance_id == "{{ matching_id_instance }}"
```

'm unable to test it because there is difficulty in setting up connectivity from my ubuntu machine to oracle cloud as I don't have required permission to add public key in the oracle cloud for my user. For connectivity I followed this: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm

I also came across a cli command to do so in oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Block/Concepts/volumereplication.htm#To_disable_boot_replication

So I actually want this ansible tasks to be verified and rectify for errors if any? Or a particular way in ansible to disable CRR in oracle cloud

Error message I'm getting at "Update boot_volume" task:

```
"msg": "Updating resource failed with exception: Parameters are invalid or incorrectly formatted. Update volume requires at least one parameter to update."}
```

Comment: Hi. Please [update you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72009574/edit) and add an [mcve](/help/mcve) showing what you have already tried, the result / error(s) you are getting and a description of what you expect instead. You might also benefit from reading [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) before you proceed with editing your post. Thanks.

Comment: The question has been updated @Zeitounator

Comment: @AnvaySingh, can you share how you are adding the public key and what error you are getting. you can follow https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm to generate and upload the public key.

Regarding ansible task, are you able to run the ansible task? If yes, can you share the error logs.

Comment: @DineshSuthar I'm unable to upload the public key on the console. I try to edit user capabilities and add API Keys option but get the message "Authorization failed or requested resource not found"

Currently I'm unable to run the ansible task

Comment: @AnvaySingh, Did you check with your administrator to add API Keys option. Maybe, you don't have permission to enable it.

Comment: @DineshSuthar I'm trying on a free version right now. API key connectivity issue is rectified. Working on the playbook now. Can I run the cli command mentioned in the question using the shell module?

Comment: @AnvaySingh, I think your ansible playbook should be able to disable CRR as you are passing "boot_volume_replicas: []" ... that is correct way to disable CRR using ansible module. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @DineshSuthar Since I'm passing [] to disable it, will it still require availability_domain parameter?

Comment: @DineshSuthar The error message I'm getting for "Update boot_volume" task:
"msg": "Updating resource failed with exception: Parameters are invalid or incorrectly formatted. Update volume requires at least one parameter to update."}

Answer (score 0):

No need to paas the `availability_domain` for disabling CRR. You can refer below ansible task for your reference.

```
- name: Disable CRR for boot_volume
  oci_blockstorage_boot_volume:
      boot_volume_id: "{{ boot_volume_id }}"
      boot_volume_replicas: []
  register: result
```

Comment: Still this error FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Updating resource failed with exception: Parameters are invalid or incorrectly formatted. Update volume requires at least one parameter to update."}

Comment: Can you share what oci-python-sdk version you are using? If possible, can you upgrade it to latest version and check if it works.

Comment: oci version: 2.65.0